# Why data not inserting to local database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

These are the fields in table.

```
public static String Table_Train_Demo = "SMS_TRAIN_DEMO";
public static String Train_DEMO_ID = "TRAIN_DEMO_ID";
public static String Train_Person_Name = "PERSON_NAME";
public static String Train_Designation = "DESIGNATION";
public static String Train_Status = "STATUS";
public static String Train_Station_Or_Place_ID = "STATION_OR_PLACE_ID";
public static String Train_Discussion_ID = "DISCUSSION_ID";
public static String Train_EMP_Status_ID = "EMP_STATUS_ID";
public static String Train_Demo_Plan_ID = "DEMO_PLAN_ID";
public static String Train_APP_Plan_ID = "APP_PLAN_ID";
public static String Train_Pk = "SMS_TRAIN_DEMO_pk";
public static String Train_Constraint = 
"SMS_TRAIN_DEMO_SMS_EMP_DAILY_STATUS";
public static String Train_Plan_Constraint = 
"SMS_TRAIN_DEMO_SMS_PLAN_TRAIN_DEMO";
public static String Train_App_Plan_Constraint = 
"SMS_TRAIN_DEMO_SMS_PLAN_APP";
```

This is the create statement of the table

```
private static final String Create_Table_Train_Demo = "CREATE TABLE " + 
Table_Train_Demo + " ("
        + Train_DEMO_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT " + Train_Pk + " 
PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + Train_Person_Name + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + Train_Designation + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + Train_Status + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + Train_Station_Or_Place_ID + " INTEGER ,"
        + Train_Discussion_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL ,"
        + Train_EMP_Status_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL ,"
        + Train_Demo_Plan_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL ,"
        + Train_APP_Plan_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL ,"
        + " CONSTRAINT " + Train_Constraint + " FOREIGN KEY (" + 
Train_EMP_Status_ID + ")"
        + " REFERENCES " + Table_Daily_EmpStatus + "(" + EStatus_ID + ")"
        + " CONSTRAINT " + Train_Plan_Constraint + " FOREIGN KEY (" + 
Train_Demo_Plan_ID + ")"
        + " REFERENCES " + Table_Plan_Train_Demo + "(" + PTrain_Demo_Plan_ID 
+ ")"
        + " CONSTRAINT " + Train_App_Plan_Constraint + " FOREIGN KEY (" + 
Train_APP_Plan_ID + ")"
        + " REFERENCES " + Table_Plan_App + "(" + PAPP_Plan_ID + ")"
        + ")";
```

Here I am trying to insert values to the table.

```
public boolean addTrngDemoEntryRecord(TRN_DEMOS recInfo, long StatusEntryID, 
long PID) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        if (db.isOpen()) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            if (recInfo != null) {
                values.put(Train_Demo_Plan_ID,PID);
                values.put(Train_APP_Plan_ID,PID);
                values.put(Train_EMP_Status_ID,StatusEntryID);
                values.put(Train_Person_Name, recInfo.PNAME);
                values.put(Train_Designation, recInfo.DESG);
                values.put(Train_Status, recInfo.STATUS);
                values.put(Train_Discussion_ID, recInfo.DID);
                values.put(Train_Station_Or_Place_ID,0);
            }
            long row_id = db.insert(Table_Train_Demo, null, values);
            if (row_id == -1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else
            return false;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("eEmp/TrngDemoplan", "Excdeption Occurred due to " + 
e.toString());
        return false;
    }  finally {
        if (db != null)
            db.close();
    }
}
```

Noexceptions are coming while table creation.

But while inserting data into the table

> long row_id = db.insert(Table_Train_Demo, null, values);

row_id = -1 is coming and `returns false` value.

what might be the problem. I am new to android.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post error or anything that you see weird in your logcat ?

Comment: It does not showing any error. row_id value -1 is coming and then returning false value. That is the problem i am facing.@MD

Comment: Use `insertOrThrow()` to get a more descriptive error message you can then log (change your logging code, too, to include exception stacktrace),

Comment: The insert method returns the id of a row just inserted or -1 if there was an error during insertion.

Comment: try to debug with `facebook/stetho`

Comment: your code looks fine

Comment: I use `insertOrThrow`. Then record is inserting and row_id value is coming as 1. What is the difference here when I am using insertOrThrow?@laalto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
log these values recInfo.PNAME, recInfo.DESG, recInfo.STATUS and recInfo.DID
as these values can't be null.
for a try just used hardcoded values 
  values.put(Train_Person_Name, "xyz");
                values.put(Train_Designation, "xyz");
                values.put(Train_Status, "xyz");
                values.put(Train_Discussion_ID,"xyz");

and check the value of row_id.
```

Comment: I checked. All values are coming.@Cansel